# Postgres Distinct or Group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with field bhk, size, price. i am using distinct to get unique by following query

1 Query

```
select distinct(bhk,size,perprice),bhk,size,price from project_units;
```

and i and also querying by

2 Query

```
select bhk, array_agg(size) as size from project_units where project_id = '12' and bhk is not null and not bhk = '1bhk' group by bhk
```

as a result i get

```
[
{
bhk:"1bhk",
size:{123,121,231}
},
{
bhk:"2bhk",
size:{223,321,131}
}


]
```

By 2 Query i also want to retrieve price also or there is any other way to get distinct on bhk size and price by 2 Query

Comment: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one (or more) of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Comment: But with multiple columns in the parens, you get a row constructor, so `distinct (a,b),c` is the same as `distinct row(a,b),c`

Answer (score 1):

and what price would you want there? as in the queries you write need to fit all data, not just for a given set. So let's imagine you have a

```
bkh='1bhk'
size='123'
price='1'
```

and

```
bhk='1bhk'
size='321'
price=2
```

so for a distinct bhk there are 2 possible prices.

If you know which price you want (min, max, average, sum) then you can add it to the query - just it needs to be a group expression